# What does forwardslash mean between two variables in an IF statement in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I am trying to understand what the forward slash between the two variables here does?

> "${lsof_line/$c2}"

Below is context. (c2_iocs is a text file)

```
lsof_output=$(lsof -i)
for lsof_line in ${lsof_output}; do
    for c2 in "${c2_iocs[@]}"; do
        # echo "$lsof_line - $c2"
        if [ "${lsof_line/$c2}" != "$lsof_line" ]; then
            log warning "[!] C2 server found in lsof output SERVER: $c2 LSOF_LINE: $lsof_line"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Removed the tag _if-statement_, since the question is related to parameter expansion, and not to testing a value. BTW, you find a good explanation about this (and other useful) parameter expansions in the bash man page; grep for the paragraph headed _Parameter Expansion_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a string replacement operation. When no replacement text is provided, the `/` following the pattern is optional. `${lsof_line/$c2}` is equivalent to `${lsof_line/$c2/}`, and both delete the string contained in `$c2` from `$lsof_line`.

Comment: Can you give an example what it does? Do you mean it cuts out the $c2 part of lsof_line, sort of like a regex and evaluates that?

Comment: ... Or does it check what $c2 is, then cuts that out from lsof_line (if it is present) in lsof_line. Then checks if lsof_line (with $c2 cut out, if it is there) is not same as (original) lsof_line?

So "${lsof_line/$c2}" first checks what $c2 is, then replace it with nothing (as the implied final / after $c2 means) in lsof_line, if lsof_line contains $c2.

Then compares lsof_line with $c2 cut out to the (original) lsof_line.

That's why it says if != (original) lsof_line, then something was found, and it shows what was found in $c2.

Got it!